# Adding and checking values within a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

So i am trying to make a menu that will present the user with a function based on their choice, the purpose of the one below is to add words and the description of that word in a list of tuples (criteria of schoolwork) but i feel like i have hit a wall with what i currently have.

```
##Lägger in nya ord i ordboken    
def menu2_val1(lista):
    lista_ord = input("Input word ")
##Looping trough the list to look for duplicate words
    for dup in lista[0]:
        if dup in lista_ord:
            print("The word already exists")
            return menu2()
        else:
            lista_definition = input("Input definition ")
            lista_ord = (lista_ord, lista_definition)
            ny_lista = list(lista)
            ny_lista.append(lista_ord)
            lista = tuple(ny_lista)
```

If the word already exists in the list it should inform the user and go back to the menu

```
def menu2():
   programm = 1
   lista = [("word", "description")]
   while programm > 0:

    print("""
    1.Insert
    2.Lookup
    3.Delete Word
    4.Exit program
    """)
    menu2=input("(Tupel Meny)What would you like to do? ")
    ## Calls on functions based on input 
    if menu2=="1":
        menu2_val1(lista)
    elif menu2=="2":
        menu2_val2(lista)
    elif menu2=="3":
        menu2_val3(lista)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closure i did manage to solve it in the end with the following code

```
def menu2_val1(lista):
lista_ord = input("Input Word ")
dup = [x[0] for x in lista]

## Storing the first value of each in tuple in dup

if lista_ord in dup:
## Looks for the new word in dup
    print("The word already exists")
    return 
else:
    lista_definition = input("Input definition ")
    nytt_ord = lista_ord, lista_definition
    lista.append (nytt_ord)
```

Potato's suggestion would end up comparing string values to tuple values which wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the line `for dup in lista[0]:`, which will only loop through the first element of `lista` instead of the whole list.

Try out `for dup in lista:` instead and see if that helps.